# foolish vs being foolish

Tags: word-usage

I heard someone say, "**You are being foolish.**"

Is there any difference between "**You are being foolish.**" and "**You are  foolish.**"?

Comment: This isn't really about "foolish" vs. "being foolish", but more about "are" vs. "are being". The same contrast applies to something like "You are a jerk" vs. "You are being a jerk."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a massive difference: *"You are being foolish."* describes a behaviour, while *"You are foolish."* describes a characteristic of the person and is likely to offend.

If someone does something foolish, it doesn't (necessarily) mean they're an inherently foolish person.  We all probably do foolish things sometimes, but don't generally consider ourselves to be **foolish people**.